# Pythonic way to split a line based on spaces coming after number

Tags: python, list, split

```
line="Map: 1   Cumulative CPU: 3.83 sec   HDFS Read: 4598507 HDFS Write: 748757 SUCCESS"
```

I have a line like this. I want a list in following mannner.

```
list=['Map: 1','Cumulative CPU: 3.83 sec','HDFS Read: 4598507','HDFS Write: 748757']
```

I'm not very comfortable with regex and the only way which i can think to achieve my obj is split this line based on spaces coming after integer and float numbers.
Can someone please help me out to resolve this.
Thanks in Adv.

Comment: why `SUCCESS` is missed from the result?

Comment: `sec` is not a number. Your input suggests that the true delimiter is a sequence of three spaces. So why not `line.split('   ')`?

Comment: Try to make pace with regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
\S[^:]*: \d+(?:\.\d+ sec)?
```

Usage:

```
re.findall(r'\S[^:]*: \d+(?:\.\d+ sec)?', line)
```

Explanation:

```
\S[^:]*        # look for a non-space character and match up to...
:              # the next colon
\d+            # followed by digits
(?:\.\d+ sec)? # and optionally some floating point digits and the string "sec"
```

Comment: it won't work if there would be such a substring `" HDFS Read:4598507 "`. But it stays good for the exact OP's input string